# Z80 register pairs

Tags: cpu-registers, machine-code, z80

I am fairly new to the Z80 and machine code, so please don't assume I know anything.

Basically, what I want to know is this: If you load register `H` with a value (I'll call it `y`), will `HL` then be `0xy0`? e.g. if `H` was loaded with `0xAF` would `HL` be `0xAF00`?
And would the same be true for loading `L` with `y`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm confident that loading a value into the H register does not effect the L register and vice versa even though the two registers may also be treated as a 16-bit register pair. However, I can't find a source that definitively states this.

Comment: @hatchet-donewithSOverflow You are correct, loading H will not touch L and vice versa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The H and L 8-bit registers can be treated independently. Loading a value in H, will not affect the value in L, and vice versa. The two registers H and L can also be treated as a 16-bit register pair. The following source [FIRST STEPS IN MACHINE CODE](http://www.nonowt.com/magfold/mcodefol/mcode2.html) describes this.

> two single register transfers, e.g.
>
> LD H, B
>
> LD L, C
>
> to copy BC into
> HL.

and

> You can, if you wish, load a register pair directly with a single
> instruction, rather than use two instructions. From last time, you
> will recall that the H and L, B and C, and D and E registers can be
> paired such that they effectively can hold any number between 0 and
> 65535 (00 to FFFF hex). C, E, and L form the low byte of the pair,
> while B, D, and H are the high bytes.